How to repeat the same test with Selenium Webdriver without opening a new browser instance each time?
I am using Selenium Webdriver on Node.js with Cucumber.js.
I want to run the same test on multiple pages. In this case just checking for 404s in my footer.
My Cucumber .feature file looks like:
Feature: Check footer links
 
    Scenario: Check for broken links in the footer section
        Given I am checking the footer on the '<page>' page
        Then there should be no broken links in the footer on '<page>' page

        Examples: 
        | page        |
        | about-us    |
        | contact-us  |
        | products    |

And in my steps.js file I have:
const { When, Then, Given, AfterAll } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const assert = require('assert');
const { Builder, By, until, Key, http } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
var {setDefaultTimeout} = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

Given('I am checking the footers on the {string} page', async function (string) {
    this.driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();
    
    this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('logo-image')));

    await this.driver.get('https://www.some-site.com/' + string);
});

Then('there should be no broken links in the footer on {string} page', async function(string) {
    var urlArr = [];
    var footerLinks = await this.driver.findElements(By.css('.footer a'));
    for (let i = 0; i < footerLinks.length; i++) {
        var url = await footerLinks[i].getAttribute("href");
        urlArr.push(url);
    }

    if (urlArr.length  < 1) {
        console.log(`Could not find any footer links on ${string} page`);
    }
    else {
        for (let i = 0; i < urlArr.length; i++) {
            var respStatus = await checkLink(urlArr[i]);
            assert.ok(respStatus==200);
        }
    }
});


function checkLink(url) {
   //Check link function returns status code....
}

This works fine, but for one thing: For each page that is tested a new instance of FireFox opens up.
I tried adding
After(async function() {
    this.driver.quit();
});

To the end but this closes the session completely and the other tests fail after the first initial one is done.
Would anyone know how I could repeat the tests in the same browser instance?

You can create a wrapper for your driver, so you can control when the driver object is created and closed.
// features/support/world.js
const { setWorldConstructor } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');

class CustomWorld {
  constructor() {
    this.driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  }

  async quit() {
    await this.driver.quit();
  }
}

setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld);

Here, quit() is called only when the CustomerWorld object is destroyed.
setWorldConstructor will make the driver available in the step definitions using this.driver.
You can configure to use this world file like this
// cucumber.js
{
  "default": {
    "require": [
      "features/support/world.js",
      "features/step-definitions/*.js"
    ],
    "format": ["pretty"]
  }
}


Thanks! Dumb question, but how then do I implement this file? Will it just pick up and run whenever I run a test or do I have to reference it in every test file?

@MeltingDog I have added how to configure the world file. "Will it just pick up and run whenever I run a test or do I have to reference it in every test file?" If configured as showed, it will be taken by Cucumber - no need to reference it on the step defintinions.

@MeltingDog If the answer is satisfactory, can you mark it as accepted? It will show others the answer resolves the problem.

Thanks for this, but I am still a bit confused. Where do I place the cucmber.js file? And how do I modify my steps.js code above to use the world. I cannot seem to find any information on how to implement this on Google. Do you know of any tutorial pages?
